# count all lines containing a string in all files in a directory and see the output for each file separately

Tags: bash

I split a file into 15 new files, each having 400 lines of text. I am trying to search each of the 15 new files for a specific string pattern but would like to know how many instances of the pattern are in each new file.

I know I can search all files in the directory using `grep -r "pattern" | wc -l` which gives me the overall number of lines that my pattern is in but I'd like to know which files -- I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet

this is what I'd like it to look like:

```
File1 100
File2 89
File3 90
```

Because of how I split the files they're all titled "FILEAA" "FILEAB" "FILEAC" etc

Comment: for loop ftw `for i in file*;do grep "pattern" -Hc $i ;done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
grep -cr "pattern" .
```

Comment: grep -cr "pattern" . | grep -v ":0" If you want to ignore zero matches.

Comment: Notice that this counts lines where the pattern occurs, which might be what you want – but if the pattern occurs multiple times on the same line, it'll be counted just once.